# Using C#, how to access a control inside WPF ResourceDictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I have a `ResourceDictionary` to define my custom Window style. I am using [WindowChrome](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ff703380(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to style my MainWindow by adding a custom title bar to it that has a button control. **Question**: Using `C#` in the code behind file `MainWindow.cs`, how can I access the button control `btnTest` residing inside the following `MyWindowChrome.xaml` file:

**MyWindowChrome.xaml**:

```xml
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyWPFProject.WindowStyle"
                        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWPFProject">
    
    <Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome ResizeBorderThickness="5" UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Button x:Name="btnTest" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application x:Class="MyWPFProject.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 xmlns:main="clr-namespace:MyWPFProject"
                 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyWPFProject;component/WindowStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show how/when you apply the `Style`. Assuming that you set the `FrameworkElement.Style` directly in the XAML file, you should be able to get the template elements when `FrameworkElement.Loaded` was raised:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var button = this.Template.FindName("btnTest", this) as Button;
  }
}
```